# How to force an MVC application to populate the User.Identity.Name value when using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I have an MVC 3 application which is to be used  for both anonymous and authenticated users.

This is accomplished by configuring IIS authentication mode to enable both anonymous and windows authentication, and then setting the authentication mode web.config setting to "Windows" and applying a custom authorization attribute selectively to actions that require the authentication check.

The issue is that in some actions I don't need to apply the attribute (so anonymous users can access it too), but in the case that an admin user is browsing it, then I want to retrieve his User.Identity.Name value.

The application is behaving unpredictably, in some instances, once the user has been authenticated in a previous action, then the User.Identity.Name property remains available for the rest of the user's session. However, in other instances, it's coming up as an empty string.

So, how do I actually tell the application to "go and authenticate this user"? If the Authorize attribute can force the authentication of the user, then how can I achieve this same effect on demand within an action?

thanks for you help,

M

Answer (score 0):

> If the Authorize attribute can force the authentication of the user,
>   then how can I achieve this same effect on demand within an action?

By doing the same as the `AuthorizeAttribute` does:

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. However, I'm not looking to reject the user as unauthenticated, but rather, I want to have their name populated in User.Identity.Name if they are actually authenticate-able if you know what I mean. Something like, if username.startsWith("admin") then User.Identity.Authenticate()... I just can't figure what is the real command or technique for this.

Comment: In other words, which line of the AuthorizeAttribute actually performs the authentication of the user?

Comment: This is done by the corresponding authentication handler and happens much earlier in the execution context than your controller action. There's absolutely nothing in the AuthorizeAttribute that does that. For example if you are using FormsAuthentication this happens in the FormsAuthentication module much earlier in the execution pipeline. This module reads the forms authentication cookie, decrypts it, extracts the username and sets the current principal.

Comment: So there is no way to ask the application to "go and authenticate this user" on demand?

Comment: Sure there is. Depending on the authentication scheme you are using you could manually populate the `User` property from the request.

Comment: This is exactly my question, how do I do that?

Comment: (I'm using a mix of Windows authentication and Anonymous, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Windows authentication is handled by IIS. If the user sent his credentials with the request the User property will be automatically populated.

Comment: It seems that only when the AuthorizeAttribute is applied to an action that the user shows up as authenticated consistently and the User.Identity.Name is populated. The issue is only showing up when I'm trying to access the User.Identity.Name property from an action that doesn't have the AuthorizeAttribute applied, even though a previous action has already authenticated the user. So, maybe the only solution then is to redirect the user to another action that has the AuthorizeAttribute applied if I've determined that the user should be authenticated. I'm gathering this is the only approach?